# passing shared_array to another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Threre's a problem with boost::shared_array. I need to allocate an array and pass it to another thread to proccess its data, and delete array after that. 
I can't understand what happens in the situation bellow:

```
void deletePtr(boost::shared_array<char> ptr)
{
    std::cout <<"c3= " <<ptr.use_count() << std::endl;
    ptr.reset();    
}
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 3)
    {

       char* a = new char[3]{'3','2','1'};
       boost::shared_array<char> ptr(a);
       std::cout << "c1= " << ptr.use_count() << std::endl;
       boost::thread t(boost::bind(deletePtr, ptr));
       std::cout <<"c2= " <<ptr.use_count() << std::endl;
       i++;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

I got this:c1 = 1, c2 = 2, c3 = 3

c1 and c2 results is what I expected, but c3 should be 1, so where two extra owners came from?
Thanks for any help

Comment: The main thread is an owner, still in scope, the thread is an owner and finally, it is copied for the function call.